# Github Invite Member button is not working

Tags: github, gitlab

Here I am invite my fellows to our organization. after selecting his ID, Invite button still disable or not working. Any one have any idea what is wrong with it
[image]

Comment: Try reloading page / using different browser. If that doesn't work try inviting another user, if that is working, the user probably has a ban.

Comment: I try different browser and also clear cache. but still same issue,

Comment: I try to add another user also. actual list view is not working, Do you try this? @kaffarell

Comment: Did you really click on the dropdown and on the name that is suggested? because it works on my machine... Remember that you cannot simply write the name and click invite, you have to write the name, click on the dropdown suggestion and then click invite

Comment: Its Resolved, I was using Ads blocker and VPN. As I close both extenstions from my browsers. its working fine. Thanks for you @kaffarell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Resolved, I was using Ads blocker and VPN. As I close both extenstions from my browsers. its working fine. Thanks for you @kaffarell